# Get to previous view or leave app onKeydown

Tags: android, view, onkeydown

I've got 1 view (frontpage)
A second view (webview)
What i'm trying to do is, when the user is on Webview, if he press the back key, he will go back to the frontpageview, if he is on frontpageview, the app will close.

i've tried something like this :

```
            @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if(findViewById(R.id.frontpage_view).getTag().equals("front")) 
                    finish();
                else if(findViewById(R.id.webView_web_app).getTag().equals("webv")) 
                    setContentView(R.layout.frontpage);}
                return true;}}
```

here are the xml from "frontpage" (the beginning)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
   android:id="@+id/frontpage_view"
android:tag="front"
 >
```

And Webview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".WebAppActivity"
 >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_web_app"
    android:tag="webv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

When the layout is frontpage, it leaves the app when the back key is pressed.
But once i'm on the webview layout, the app crash when i press the backkey.
i'm i doing this right?

Answer (score 0):

Use Activities and Fragmens for managing your views. Read about [proper back navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).